# How to group the formula field results in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want Number of cartons and Pieces currently available in the stock that are about to expire in next 30 days and this is calculated based on expiry date...I have used formula field on crystal report to calculate current stock like "stock.crtns_added - stock.crtns_removed" and "stock.pieces_added - stock.pieces_removed"....Now I want to group by item name, category and expirydate because based on these three columns there can be more than 1 entries in the database....I want that when there are more than one entries the formula should sum up all the cartons and pieces for same item of a category with same expiry date and on report it should display just 1 line showing available cartons and pieces that are about to expire

How can i do this?? How can I apply group clause on the formula field in crystal report to get sum of cartons or pieces for each item based on expiry date??

Answer (score 2):

You can Insert Group for each group you want. You can nest the groups and put the formula inside the inner-most grouping and it should give you sums grouped how you want. You'll end up with something similar to this:

```
Report Header
Page Header
Group Header 1 (category)
 Group Header 2 (item name)
  Group Header 3 (expiry date)
   Details
  Group Footer 3 - summation formulas possibly go here
 Group Footer 2
Group Footer 1
Page Footer
Report Footer
```